# There's a gap in my mobile css

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am having trouble styling my site for mobile. Currently there's a big gap between the header div and the nav div if you view the site on your smartphone. Here's a simulator that you can test http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php?u=http://toarumajutsunoindex.me/ does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: #header has fixed height 500px. Remove it in mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're main style sheet listed the height of the header div as 500px. This was never changed by your mobile sheet. Removing that line fixed it in the emulator.